# Restream youtube live channel wth vlc or ffmpeg`

Tags: stream, ffmpeg, vlc

Is it possible to restream a channel with vlc or ffmpeg? I dont think neither will take youtube url as input for restreaming - would there need to be url snooping or w/e its called to get the proper input url?